# 2002 Honda Civic, will not start without maintenance override procedure?

Tags: honda, starting, civic

I have a 2002 Honda Civic. This vehicle has been running great for a long time.

Right now if I want to start the car I have to use the maintenance override procedure:

1. Push the reset button on the dash.
2. Turn the ignition on for 10 seconds.
3. Turn off the ignition.
4. Then start the car.

The car has recently had a fresh oil change and general tune up.  This maintenance took place two weeks ago. The car has been running great and runs great after the maintenance override code is done to start up the car.

This procedure is printed in my owners manual.  Why would I have to use the maintenance override in order to start this car?

Comment: What happens if you try to start the car normally? Did the problem start right after you took it to the shop?

Comment: When you start the car the engine doesn't do anything. I can not hear the starter or any moving parts.  This happened the first time about two weeks out of the shop.

Comment: So, like it just started in the last few days? I'm impressed that you figured out the override procedure! My first thought would be that something didn't get reattached quite right after the service and it came loose.

Comment: Is the reset button the one on the instrument cluster between the speedometer and the fuel gauge? I've been searching to find a description of the procedure and to see if I can find what triggers it, but so far the only thing I've come up with is a process for resetting the service reminder light that is similar to what you're describing here. But I don't find any indication that it would stop the car from starting.

Comment: It sounds like a security system problem. If the car starts and runs with the service override that means everything is working with battery and starter and what not.

Comment: can you capture a video of what you have to do to start the car? one shouldn't have to do with the other as the instrument cluster isn't used in the anti-theft system except for the indicator.